# C/C++ macro error with quotes and backslashes

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am trying to spice up my testing framework for a scripting language with some nice C macros to not to have to write the same code more than once ... So, I have the code:

```
TEST_CASE("Variables", "[vm_variables]")
{
nap_runtime* runtime = nap_runtime_create(0);
REQUIRE(runtime != 0);

nap_bytecode_chunk* bytecode = nap_runtime_compile(runtime, 
                 "                            \
                  int a;                      \
                  a = 2;                      \
                 "
                );
REQUIRE(bytecode != 0);
int t = nap_runtime_execute(runtime, bytecode);
REQUIRE(1 == t);
REQUIRE(2 == nap_runtime_get_int(runtime, "a"));
free(runtime);
}
```

As it is right now it creates a runtime where it executes the code (`int a; a=2;`), and this works...

And I was thinking to extract the creation parts into a macro, like the one below, in a way that I have to write only the script ... so I came up with:

```
#define SCRIPT_START nap_runtime* runtime = nap_runtime_create(0);              \
                 nap_bytecode_chunk* bytecode = nap_runtime_compile(runtime,    \
                 "

#define SCRIPT_END  "  \
                ); \
                int t = nap_runtime_execute(runtime, bytecode); 

TEST_CASE("Variables", "[vm_variables]")
{
SCRIPT_START                    \ <<------------- HERE
    int a;                      \
    a = 2;                      \
SCRIPT_END

REQUIRE(2 == nap_runtime_get_int(runtime, "a"));
free(runtime);
}
```

And in my head this works nicely, but the compiler does not like it... where the HERE is it give mes the following error:

```
test.cpp: error: missing terminating " character
```

I have changed, and modified it several rotations, still the same... What do I do wrongly?

**EDIT:**
After compiling with `-E` here is the relevant part:

```
44633     {                                                                           
44634     nap_runtime* runtime = nap_runtime_create(0); nap_bytecode_chunk* bytecode = nap_runtime_compile(runtime, "
44635         int a;                                                                  
44636         a = 2;                                                                  
44637     "                      );                     int t = nap_runtime_execute(runtime, bytecode);                     REQUIRE(1 == t);
44638
```

so it seems the `\` from the line with the `SCRIPT_START` macro is being ignored ... and also the other following lines. Why?

**EDIT2** Experimenting and having fun with the compiler:

Now, I put TWO backslashes:

```
TEST_CASE("Variables", "[vm_variables]")
{
SCRIPT_START                    \\ <<------------- HERE
    int a;                      \\
    a = 2;                      \\
SCRIPT_END
```

the output via `-E` is:

```
44634     nap_runtime* runtime = nap_runtime_create(0); nap_bytecode_chunk* bytecode = nap_runtime_compile(runtime, " \
44635         int a; \                                                                
44636         a = 2; \                                                                
44637     "                      );                     int t = nap_runtime_execute(runtime, bytecode);                     REQUIRE(1 == t);
```

and the error is almost the same:

```
test.cpp:19:5: error: missing terminating " character
test.cpp:19:5: error: stray ‘\’ in program
```

so regardless, that with two backslashes it generates "correct" code that still fails to compile :)

Comment: Tell the compiler to not actually compile the code, but only run the preprocessor, and look at the preprocessed output to see what's really being produced. With e.g. GCC or clang you use the `-E` option, don't know how to do it in Visual Studio (or other IDEs).

Comment: GCC lets you see the preprocessor output when you run with `gcc -E`.  I don't know what compiler you're using, but if it has a mode that lets you see the preprocessed output, I suggest trying it to see what might be happening above.

Comment: Nobody has stated the obvious yet: Why use macros here? This seems to lead to horrible bugs (like this one). The only thing you are doing is create a string that you pass into your functionality - Why not call a function that takes a string?

Comment: I just want to extract the "fixture" functionality of the unit test framework into a few lines of macro.

Comment: @domhege:  It can make sense to hide these things behind macros if you have many, many tests, and the part behind macros actually never changes.  Once the stuff behind the macros works and is solid, then someone coming to a test case in this framework really only needs to understand the test case and not the rest of the framework most of the time.

Comment: @fritzone:  Regarding Edit 2:  Backslashes are handled at preprocessing time.  Just as you can't have a macro leave behind a `#define` for later, it also can't leave behind a backslash for later, as I understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have an unmatched `"` in a `#define` macro. The contents of a macro must be tokenizable. A string literal token is not a complete token if it doesn't have both begin and end quotes.

The other answers about backslashes and such are wrong. You simply cannot have unmatched quotes in macros. See this example program, which does not compile:

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BEGIN_QUOTE "
#define END_QUOTE "

int main() {
    printf(BEGIN_QUOTE hello world!\n END_QUOTE);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c:3:21: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
test.c:4:19: warning: missing terminating " character [enabled by default]
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:5: error: missing terminating " character
test.c:7:24: error: ‘hello’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:7:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test.c:7:30: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘world’
test.c:7:30: error: stray ‘\’ in program
test.c:7:30: error: missing terminating " character
```

You'll have to leave the quotes outside of the macros and write them explicitly:

```
SCRIPT_START
"            \
    int a;   \
    a = 2;   \
"
SCRIPT_END
```

Comment: Good point, and one I certainly failed to consider.  I'll delete my misleading answer.